# Using a method decorator to change the function return type

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

Below I have a sync function that returns a boolean, I am using this decorator `@MakeAsync` to change the function. I am curious how I can update the return type of the function after this change has been made. I tried using `Promise<ReturnType<typeof original>>`, but that failed.

Is it possible for a decorator to overwrite the type definition (parameters, and return type) of a method?

```
function MakeAsync() {
    console.log("f(): evaluated");
    return function (target, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const original = descriptor.value;
        if (typeof original === 'function') {
            descriptor.value = async (...args): Promise<ReturnType<typeof original>> => {
                return original(...args)
            }
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}

class Example {    
    @MakeAsync()
    doTrue (): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}

const e = new Example

console.log(e.doTrue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorators don't mutate types as far as I know.  I know [class decorators don't](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), anyway.  You can probably make your own function which takes a class constructor and returns a new class constructor with modified prototype methods, and manually annotate that's what it does, but you wouldn't be using decorator notation for that.  Decorators are syntactic sugar for function calls anyway, so if the former doesn't work for you, the latter should be more flexible.

Here's one possibility:

```
type Asyncify<C extends new (...args: any) => any,
    K extends keyof InstanceType<C>> = new (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) => {
        [P in keyof InstanceType<C>]: P extends K ?
        InstanceType<C>[K] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ?
        (...args: A) => Promise<R> : InstanceType<C>[K]
        : InstanceType<C>[K]
    };

function makeMethodAsync<
    C extends new (...args: any) => any,
    K extends keyof InstanceType<C>
>(ctor: C, methodName: K): Asyncify<C, K> {
    const c = class extends (ctor as any) { };
    c.prototype[methodName as any] = async function (...args: any) {
        return ctor.prototype[methodName].apply(this, args);
    }
    return c as any;
}
```

That implementation uses a lot of `any` type assertions to quiet the compiler.  Basically the type `Asyncify<C, K>` takes a constructor type `C` and an instance property name `K` (which should really be a method name; I don't check for that) and evaluates to another constructor type whose instance has returns a `Promise` for that method `K` and leaves the other properties alone.  And the implementation does a similar thing with the prototype of the new subclass it creates.  (I tried to take some care to deal with the `this` context properly; I think your decorator might do bad things to class instances  whose methods access properties or other methods).

Let's see if it works:

```
const Example = makeMethodAsync(class Example {
    prop = "hey";
    syncDoTrue() {
        console.log(this.prop)
        return true;
    }
    asyncDoTrue() {        
        console.log(this.prop)
        return true;
    }

}, "asyncDoTrue");

const e = new Example(); 

const b = e.syncDoTrue(); // hey
console.log(b); // true

const r = e.asyncDoTrue(); // hey
console.log(r); // Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: true }
```

Looks good to me, I guess.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggziAdgYwJYDMQB4DCUIAewEiAJnFIhAO5QAUAdEwIYBOA5nAFxTOIgBKKAF4AfL34AaALAAoKAqgBpfERLkoAawggA9uigBJRHGB9kEACrgIuUeOGUa9JgzaceOXSeCsArsjAuqwACmzMALYQxKxwdkJiUADecoppUADaIVCoiFo6+kY+5lY2dgC6PNmExGQUKgD8qekKxqYl1pB2GUrlqrUajCwc3DmI6BCssAniuRNTAEpQTfItLsMe0yLiIay6EahwtgviPG1mKKVdOKI95c0tZ8WXnbY3dw9QAL4A3HJy6D8KGAqG8UAizG0AFlogALXSkeBIZBYT54GrqChUWhDNwjHh8QTbCQgGSrBQqDF1fJ6AznDplG5yUR0QLBTyScFwhEAOUiEB4SgEPCRKAw2BwnKU4hS5KgyG8pnlInlABtmHAKFTBmyphqSUIkt8-nLkAwwHsgqBIBkosB4aQ+VFeBRCX1HBrkVBAcDQXlce5RoTDZ80qxon5WHldebLbprRBbdzHfzym4wGBVSA6PbDpzAwITWkvp9w8BI9GXSSTSXZHIFT4oABRAiRTPQRwQ6HJ0XIVnqzXN1sRdvJT4W3RgFUAIlhOmnRcUCBQABFdJZ-BA6CG5WkG3BdKqIAxVbp2DnYYdY5OBKHFGWK1BfH4IIuFLW0p7V+vN9vkmsoDvBR90PY9T3PXM4GvMBb13e8IyjJ9Nzfb5-lkL5OWnL9kDXDcX2nQs0P3YB8BVbEhzbI9tx+QC61kYioAAIxVY9lxwn8X2oqAAHpuKgOcQHrRVQJPM86EYwseL458ICIxUSKmRxj2w3Df0k3j+J0ISTBE8C6FYdS+N2fZDmgI0sHaYhRB4adAVVdBUFVI9SGnTksAAN2YVUX2spCX1Qui0KAA)