# Typescript class decorator doesn't work the way it is expected

Tags: typescript, class-decorator

I have the example code below:

```
function BaseEntity(ctr: Function) {
    ctr.prototype.id = Math.random();
    ctr.prototype.created = new Date();
  }

@BaseEntity
class User {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

let user = new User("Sarah");
console.log(user.id);
```

When I run this i got

`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'.`

The `experimentalDecorators` property is enabled.

What is the problem?

Comment: A decorator cannot change the type of what it's decorating. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685432/using-a-method-decorator-to-change-the-function-return-type and this open typescript issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Comment: Thank you! In the official documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) there is an example with the same error. Hmm...